# How to amend table of content character entry style in InDesign, NOT paragraph style

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, table-of-contents

When I create a table of contents in InDesign, it asks me to pick my paragraph entry style for the chapter text. However, it does not give me the option to edit the character style, meaning that it looks exactly the same as my chapter headings in the document, which I do not want.

I have tried making the style and colour of the paragraph style different, but it does not appear to change anything. You can see what I mean here:

[image: Image 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily choose whatever paragraph style you want for each level of entry.

In the "Table of Contents" dialogue, make sure to have the included Paragraph Style highlighted, then you can choose the Paragraph Style for the table of contents using "Entry Style". (Please note that this is a Paragraph Style and not a Character Style, which is for styling individual characters within a paragraph.)

[image: TOC]

You can also choose the Character Style for the page number, which characters to put between the entry and the page number (default is a tab character) and the Character Style for the characters between the entry and the page number.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think that because I had a paragraph style and character style applied to the text, it was using the character style over the paragraph style. I turned the character style off and did the above and it worked fine! Thanks again!

Comment: Good to hear! Styles can be quite confusing! And TOCs too. Strange things can happen if you style the headers too much. Automatic numbering can give problems and forced line breaks show up in the TOC. Sometimes I give up and style the TOC manually at the very end of the project.

Comment: Yes, I agree. TOCs sound way more complicated than they have to be! I may end up doing it manually at the end, but at least I know how to do it now. Thanks :)